# PDF Box Calibri Font Issue

Tags: fonts, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox to fill a fillable PDF with font set Calibri. User enters the value in a form and those values get set in respective fillable fields. When user presses Enter (New Line), PDF shows a junk character “?”. If I change the font Helvetica, its working properly.

Can you please suggest what I am missing and where?

Comment: what PDFBox version are you using?

Comment: I had issues with Calibri and PDFBox on and off. Sometimes PDFBox can't read the calibri text, sometimes it can't. Any updates? This was using 1.8.7

Comment: I am having same issue with Corbel. Also, PDPage.getResources().getFonts() is always giving me Corbel and Arial fonts. I am not getting from where it is getting that Corbel Font. Please help if you know this issue.

Comment: I got my problem solved. I was using PDPageContentStream for manipulation of PDF. When I added a hidden text containing '0123456789.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxz,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYXZ' chars, it worked fine. Because I set the font of hidden line to Corbel. This is strange but it is now working awesome !